# Finding a / symbol in string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a forward slash in a string...

This doesn't seem to work:

```
if ("/test".indexOf("/") > -1) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Funny thing is... I tried this:

```
if ("!test".indexOf("!") > -1) {
```

and it works! I also tried \/ for that... help?

Comment: `System.out.println("/test".indexOf("/") > -1);` prints `true` here. Your problem certainly lies somewhere else. Trust me.

Comment: @Dan - how you concluded that it doesn't work?
is that really Java?

Comment: @Carlos: There is no language in which the first line won't work but the second will. (AFAIK)

Comment: @SLaks - sorry, but I don't know all languages... but can imagine some where you can override `indexOf` (with `/` being a special character?), or which do not have a standard `indexOf` at all.

Comment: @Carlos: Then the second line won't work either.

Comment: I think the reason is because I check it like this if ("/kick dan".indexOf("/") > -1) { and it would return false but if i split it up using a space delimeter and did this:if (whoKick[0].indexOf("/") > -1) { -- it worked.

Comment: leading space, you mean?

Comment: ​‌‍‎‏‎ ​‌‍‎‏‎ ​ ​     Yes, I do.

Comment: which string are you talking about?

Comment: @Dan: The string returned by `say.getText()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a String starts with a given character, use `charAt(0)` to get that charracter

```
    if (text.charAt(0) == '/') {
```

or `startsWith(String)` to check for more than one character (a String)

```
    if (text.startsWith("/kick ")) {
```

EDIT:
use `trim()` to delete leading and trailing spaces if needed:

```
    if (text.trim().charAt(0) == '/') {
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [contains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
if("/test".contains("/"))
```

However both of your methods should work and both did work in my tests.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This does essentially the same. It's just a shorthand introduced in Java 1.5. Check the source code.

Comment: @Dan: still, your *actual* problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Your `say.getText()` call is probably returning a string that doesn't start with `/`.
(See comment)

For example, it might be starting with `∕` (U+2215 DIVISION SLASH), or with a space  (or with a `\` backslash).

**EDIT**: You have whitespace <strike>or a non-printing character</strike> before the `/`.          *Trust me*.

Comment: If you try the line of code you put in your question, does it work?

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
        System.out.println("!test".indexOf("!"));
        System.out.println("/test".indexOf("/"));
 }
```

This correctly prints

```
0
0
```